# How do I pick images from folder and display in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a image slideshow. Presently I write a simple code to display images. Now when I add new images to the same folder I have to again update the code for displaying the new image. How do I make it dynamic so that the code automatically picks the image and displays in the HTML page.

```html
<body>

  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
  <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>

  <script>
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
      }
      if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
      }
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: If you mean a folder on the server, then you would need to use write some server-side code to serve the list of files/folders and their paths (either statically as the page is built, or via AJAX). If you mean a folder on the client, then that's not possible for security reasons.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan All the files would be in a single folder on the server. So the source path would be the same every time except for the filename. I am eager to know how I could read this filename with Ajax, so that by adding an image in the folder I could display it on the html page.

Comment: You could write some server side code (PHP, C#, Node, Python, Ruby etc) to retrieve all the files in the folder, then return their paths to the JS through AJAX. Then you can populate the slides from those paths.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, if you are not using server side scripting, you can use a JavaScript array and insert images. Will not work for 50 images, it's cumbersome.

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function(){
     // insert your images here
     var imgs = [ 'one.jpg', 'two.jpg' ];
     var div, img;
     for( var x = 0; x < imgs.length;x++ ){
           div = document.createElement('div');
           div.className = 'mylides fade';
           img = document.createElement('img');
           img.src = imgs[x];
           div.appendChild( img );
           document.querySelector('.slideshow-container').insertBerofe( div, document.querySelector('.next') );

    }
  }, false

 )
```